# I don't know how to sort by condition in scala

Tags: scala

sort in descending order of date, if same, sort by name, if same, sort by highest score
in English, math, and science.

```
object OptionAnswer {
    case class Score(
      name:    String,    
      english: Int,       
      math:    Int,       
      science: Int,       
      date:    LocalDate  
    )
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    
    val scoreSeq: Seq[Score] = List(scoreOfAlice,scoreOfBob,scoreOfCharlie,scoreOfDave)
val keys = Seq(-5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(sortScore(scoreSeq, keys))
  }
def sortScore(scoreSeq: Seq[Score], keys: Seq[Int]): Seq[Score] = {
    val keys_set = keys.toSet
    keys_set match{
      case 1 => scoreSeq.sortBy(score => score.name)
      case 2 => scores.sortBy(score => -score.english)
      case 3 => scores.sortBy(score => -score.math)
      case 4 => scores.sortBy(score => -score.science)
      case -1 => scoreSeq.sortBy(score => -score.name)
      case -2 => scores.sortBy(score => score.english)
      case -3 => scores.sortBy(score => score.math)
      case -4 => scores.sortBy(score => score.science)
      case _ => score
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)
I don't quite understand your details including `enter code here`.

If you improve it, it'd be easier to help you with. Thank you and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by writing the function to sort by a single key:

```
def sortByKey(scores: Seq[Score], key: Int): Seq[Score] = {
  val res = math.abs(key) match {
    case 1 => scores.sortBy(_.name)
    case 2 => scores.sortBy(-_.english)
    case 3 => scores.sortBy(-_.math)
    case 4 => scores.sortBy(-_.science)
    case _ => scores
  }
  if (key < 0) {
    res.reverse
  } else {
    res
  }
}
```

Then you can just use `foldLeft` to apply the sort to a list of keys:

```
def sortScores(scores: Seq[Score], keys: Seq[Int]): Seq[Score] =
  keys.distinct.reverse.foldLeft(scores)(sortByKey)
```

The keys are `distinct` to remove duplicates and in `reverse` because the most important key is the one applied last.

The alternative is to use the list of keys to create a single complex ordering function but I'll leave someone else to write that solution.

Comment: Is it impossible to write within a single function?

Comment: Can you say why you want it as a single function? `sortByKey` could be implemented inline in `foldLeft` but I don't see any benefit.